# Python mock the function called twice should return different return values

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to unit test the function, the function calling this function twice

`BigQueryConnector(project=getenv("PROJECT_ID", default="project_id")).query_to_pandas(query)`

am trying to use

`@patch("BigQueryConnector.query_to_pandas")`
How do I make sure that mock_method.return_value returns 2 different data frames depending on where it is called? Or is there any approach to return different mocked data frames

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help others help you and to make the question valuable for other readers.

Comment: @nutim You can use: `side_effect = [value1, value2]` instead of return_value.